# AWS is still serving the expired certificate even after associating a new one with the load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I have a web app on AWS at https://demo.titusgt.com with an AWS Certificate Manager (ACM) certificate.

It was running fine, shown as Secure site in browsers, up until my certificate expired. From the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/managed-renewal.html) I understood that ACM certificates should be automatically renewed, but this didn't happen.

So I went ahead and requested a new ACM certificate following [this procedure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request.html), the domain owner approved, I associated the new certificate with my Elastic Load Balancer following [this procedure](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-update-ssl-cert.html#us-update-lb-SSLcert-console), but AWS is still serving the old, expired certificate to my browser, so it shows up as an Insecure site.

Then I provisioned a new certificate with Let's Encrypt, [imported it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/import-certificate-api-cli.html#import-certificate-cli) into the AWS Certificate Manager and associated it with my Elastic Load Balancer, but AWS is still serving the old, expired certificate.

I also checked SSLLabs, it says that the certificate is expired.

How can I get AWS to serve the new certificate? Am I missing a step in my setup?

Comment: Did you update the certificate on the underlying web servers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`demo.titusgt.com` is a CNAME to `ec2-54-147-110-134.compute-1.amazonaws.com` - an individual EC2 instance. As a result, no Elastic Load Balancer is involved in requests to this URL, and as such, it really doesn't matter if you've assigned an SSL certificate to an ELB.

Point the domain at the ELB, or put an SSL certificate directly on the EC2 instance.

Comment: Good investigative work.